# How to retrieve cart items for a specific customer by woocommerce api

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I can't find any specific rest api to retreive cart items for a customer in woocommerce api documentation.
I've been searching this site http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#introduction many times, but nothing useful can be found.

Be glad someone help  me.